# Regex to extract number after a certain string

Tags: regex, string, r

How can I in R extract the number that always comes after the string `-{any single letter}`, e.g. from the vector:

```
c("JFSDLKJ-H465", "FJSLKJHSD-Y5FSDLKJ", "DFSJLKJAAA-Z3216FJJ")
```

one should get:

```
(465, 5, 3216).
```

The `-{any single letter}` pattern occurs only once.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: `-[a-zA-Z](\d+)` Don't know R, don't need to be downvoted. Its just a regex.

Comment: Yes I tried different stuff but am not familiar with regular expressions, and couldnt get it together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `gsub`, e.g.:

```
x <- c("JFSDLKJ-H465", "FJSLKJHSD-Y5FSDLKJ", "DFSJLKJAAA-Z3216FJJ")
as.numeric(gsub("^.*-[A-Z]+([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", x))
# [1]  465    5 3216
```

Comment: +1 - While not as robust as your example, something simple like `gsub("[^0-9]","",x)` will also work for the example data to just scrape out the numbers.

Comment: No big deal, he did say _single_ letter. If the pattern occurs only once (OP's words), shouldn't need anchors or .*

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
v <- c("JFSDLKJ-H465", "FJSLKJHSD-Y5FSDLKJ", "DFSJLKJAAA-Z3216FJJ")
as.numeric(sapply(str_match_all(v, "\\-[a-zA-Z]([0-9]+)"),"[")[2,])
## [1]  465    5 3216
```

Comment: i tend to use `stringr` as a hammer. i'm sure there's a more compact way to do this.

Comment: Whats the reason `-` needs to be escaped? Is it because its a literal non-metachar? Or, does R use this class construct `-[]`?

Comment: force of habit. it doesn't need to be escaped, but i switch between so many langs where regex strings need to be done that way i usually end up with the least common denominator in all of them.

Comment: The `[` is actually a function in R. Whenever you do something like  `FUN="["`, the 1st arg is the current element of the list (being iterated over). While the subsequent arguments are the indexes to `"["`. If separate out the `str_match_all(v, "\\-[a-zA-Z]([0-9]+)")` call & look at results then do the `sapply(str_match_all(v, "\\-[a-zA-Z]([0-9]+)"),"[")` you'll get a rly good idea of just what the `"["` did. I cld also paste a longer 'splain in an edited version of the actual answer if that'd help.

Answer (score 1):

```
> x <- c("JFSDLKJ-H465", "FJSLKJHSD-Y5FSDLKJ", "DFSJLKJAAA-Z3216FJJ")
> as.numeric(gsub("[A-Z]|-", "", x))
## [1]  465    5 3216
```

Comment: Thanks - but i realize my examples were not quite exhaustive since some strings goes like "JDSHS37283FSD-J321DKF", i.e. also with digits before the "-". So the pattern need be using the "-{single capital letter}{number}" which is unique.